# How to know the folder size in a zipfile

Tags: python, directory, size, python-zipfile

I know that you can get the size in bytes of a file in a ZIP file using the .file_size method
But is there any what I can get the size of a folder instead?

Ex:

```
import zipfile, os

os.chdir('C:\\')    
zp= zipfile.ZipFile('example.zip')

spamInfo = zp.getinfo('spam.txt')    #Here, Instead of a file I'd like to put a folder
spamInfo.file_size

zp.close()
```

Comment: You might need to loop for the files in the folder. Then get the info with zp.getinfo('file'). Then just increase a variable with the file_size each time.

Comment: `sum(zp.getinfo(filename).file_size for filename in folder)`?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, I'm new in this but what's the correct way of writing a folder. Example. If I have a folder named 'Drawings' on the zip file. should I put = >   for filename in  '\\Drawings'?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```py
import zipfile

zp = zipfile.ZipFile("example.zip")

size = sum([zinfo.file_size for zinfo in zp.filelist])
zip_kb = float(size) / 1000  # kB
```

Comment: You don't need to build a list, `sum` will work with the comprehension expression.

Comment: This only work for reliable zip sources, it is no reliable for user/attacker-origin source, for that you have to physically read through the files - read and count bytes as you go.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to vectorize this instead of the for loop and get the output in a dataframe?